# Data Encryption Standard test vectors

Tags: vhdl, des

Does anyone know where I can find test vectors for every component of 64bit DES algorithm(Key schedul, cipher function, etc)? For example I want to test 64bits key generation and to ckeck all 16 key generated. I am implementing the algorithm in VHDL so I need to check the comonents. My implementation is based on this [paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally there was NBS Special Publication 500-20, revised in 1980, Validating the Correctness of Hardware Implementations of the NBS Data Encryption Standard (The author has made it available at https://archive.org/details/validatingcorrec00gait ).

Then there is NIST Special PUB 800-17, Modes of Operation Validation System (MOVS):
Requirements and Procedures, covering FIPS PUB 46-2 (DES) as well as Skipjack. http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-17/800-17.pdf .

There's also NIST Special PUB 800-20, Modes of Operation Validation System for the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TMOVS): Requirements and Procedures. http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-20/800-20.pdf .

There may be other publications such as NIST Special Publication 800-67, Recommendation for the TripleData Encryption Algorithm (TDEA) Block Cipher, http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-67-Rev1/SP-800-67-Rev1.pdf, found at  http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html .

Having implemented DES numerous times in software and a couple of times in VHDL, it's in understanding that the DES standard originally described conformance to the hardware implementation patented by IBM in 1977. (see [vhdl_des.tar.gz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abjv929qo0kb90o/vhdl_des.tar.gz?dl=1), which is a simple implementation with an 8 bit interface.  There's a pdf file than includes a description of the I/O permutations.)

To save you the typing the test vectors from FIPS SP PUB 500-20 can be found here [des.test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y72k3blly9b4j9w/des.test?dl=1).   There may be a parity error in one of the keys, I can never keep track of which of these files is where (des -tv < des.test, a software implementation).  Someone laboriously typed them in by hand from Numerical Recipes in C, where someone had gotten them from 500-20.

Answer (score 0):

https://styere.000webhostapp.com/JS-DES.html (new link)

Enter key and data and it generates all intermediate values, for every step of the key schedule and for every step within every round.

Comment: Eugene Steyer's web pages have moved recently and the JS-DES.html file's javascript has been modified for years making it not possible to enter keys different than the defaults to prevent short cuts in homework assignments. A version with settable keys may be found dpades/trunk/simu_js/JS-DES.html in the Google Code archive downloaded from [dpades](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dpades/source/default/source). It can be very useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Heh, unchangeable key? lol. Everyone with a bit of crypto/hacker affinity edits the DOM and removes the `readonly` property from the textfield

Comment: This answer to [cryptography - DES encryption function give me a cipher text that is wrong - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397607/des-encryption-function-give-me-a-cipher-text-that-is-wrong/39415148#39415148) gives directions for modifying Eugene Steyer's [JS-DES.HTML](https://styere.000webhostapp.com/JS-DES.html) (it's new location). The implementation has been validated.